# Choosing the right data grid

Tags: java, grid

We are currently using [gigaspaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/) in our system , which is a very nice computation grid , but it is very expensive.

I am searching for some other (less expensive/free) alternatives in this field of cloud computing and computational data grids which should be java based or at least have an java API.

One of the alternatives that I have found was , [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) which seems quite nice and has the most cloud features we need.

If you know some other alternatives, or have to say something about the subject I would be more than happy to hear it.